# toSql() on Eloquent Relationship returning `where id = null`

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

**I'm working on 3-dimensional pivot table**

**Architecture**

I've made the following tables and models.

```
register_colleges( model: RegisterCollege )
- college_id
- random field

programs ( model: Program )
- id
- program_name

courses ( model: Course )
- id
- course_name

course_program_register_college
- course_id
- program_id
- college_id
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that my view shows `null` result when I try to access the `program_name` (say). This is expected by me because when I convert it toSql(), it shows the following query-

> select * from 'programs' inner join 'course_program_register_college' on 'programs'.'id' = 'course_program_register_college'.'program_id' where 'course_program_register_college'.'college_id' is null

I'm unable to figure out why this query is trying to fetch data `where 'course_program_register_college'.'college_id' is null`.

**RegisterCollege.php (model)**

```
// pivot table is looking for register_college_id as a primary key field
protected $primarykey = 'college_id';

  public function programs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Program', 
    'course_program_register_college', 'college_id');
  }
```

EDIT:-

**Eloquent Query**

```
{{ $college->programs()->toSql() }} // in some view.blade.php
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you do your eloquent query

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: and how did you get the `$college` var? is this a non existing model instance?

Comment: I have passed it to my view.blade.php via route. It contains information about a particular college.

Comment: I've found the solution of the problem by changing the model function as such- 

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Program', 'course_program_register_college', 'college_id', 'program_id')->distinct('program_id');`
Though I still don't know why it was giving a null result in the first case.